# coredata problem after changing property type

Tags: iphone, core-data

I had coredata working fine, until I needed to change 2 entitys from integer to string,
now I get

```
The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store
```

I tried deleting the app from the simulator, deleting the actual simulator file, deleting the build result, and changing the app name, to no avail,,, (I read something of deleting the xml, but cannot find it with the name of my app)

what to do please!!, I would not want to start over!!
thanks

Comment: did you delete the build directory in your project folder

Comment: try also this: in menu:build:clean all targets... sometimes it works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delete the persistent store. It will be in your application support folder. If you're running in simulator, then i believe it is in the simulator's application support folder.

EDIT: The simulators application support folder is in

`Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`

Poke around in there. You'll find what you're looking for.

Also, for ease of development with core data, sometimes what i do is delete the file when it fails to load. Make sure you post a log message so you know there was a loading issue. That way you won't have to manually delete the file whenever the store fails to load due to changes in the object model.

Comment: I find that while developing Core Data apps, keeping the app's folder handy is a must: every time you change the persistent store while developing a given version you have to delete the file. If you're building an upgrade to an existing app then you'll need to set up a migration instead, mind you.